# vba Change event at specific time

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to write a code that when a date is entered on a certain column it will call a macro at a specific time, like lets say today's date was entered on column M (which will trigger the change event) then at 5:30pm it will call a macro.

I have the coding for the change event, but I don't know how to code it to only call the Macro at a specific time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 5 Then               
        If Target.Value = Date Then         'If the target value is today
           Call Lilly
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Application.OnTime()` method to schedule another procedure for a set time.